What is the part number of this angled bar part?
I can't find this specific piece on the Bricklink inventory under category "bar".  Nor in any of the Technic categories I thought it might be found.  What is its part number?


That's 30031 Utensil Handlebars.
I found it by looking at some old Jet Ski sets I used to own that used it, then looking at parts inventory. Keyword searches weren't helpful in finding it.

Thanks, that's it!
